# Скролл с якорем в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html

Ребят, сделал скролл в модальном окне и в меню табов сделал 'якорь' , должно было получится , что при нажатии определенного таба контент плавно переходил вниз или верх но получилось так , что когда нажимаю на второй таб контент резко переходит вниз аналогично и с первым табом и еще одна ошибка что действие можно выполнять всего лишь один раз и потом табы не работают до перезагрузки страницы . что я сделал не так

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var id = $(this).attr('href'),
      top = $(id).offset().top;

  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
<section id="tab1">
    <video class="videocontent" controls poster="images/preview.jpg">
        <source src="images/ps.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    </video>
</section>
<section id="tab2">
    <img src="images/background.jpg">
</section>
</div>
<div class="leftcol">
    <img class="img1" src="images/ps4.jpg">
    <img class="img2" src="images/logo.jpg">
    <div class="tabs" id="menu">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav_item">
                <a href="#tab1">Video</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_item">
                <a href="#tab2">Horizon Zero Dawn</a></br>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_item">
              <a href="#tab3">Through Aloy's Eyes</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vmtye285/
плавный переход по вашему коду работает... Или в чем проблема?
Ctrl+F5 пробовали?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vmtye285/3/ посмотрите мой полный код , у меня почему то не работает @Oleksandr

Comment: У вас вылазит ошибка, что нет элемента с id `tab3`. Ну и скрол по идее может работать, только если есть куда скролить, те контент больше высоты окна и появился скроллбар

Comment: @Crantisz а как написать эту jquery функцию  на чистом javascriptе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас три ошибки.

1.У вас вылазит ошибка, что нет элемента с id `tab3`. *Хотя это скорее просто недоделка*

2.Cкрол по идее может работать, только если есть куда скролить, те контент больше высоты окна и появился скроллбар. я добавил высоты:

```
.main section{
  min-height:600px;
}
```

3.Если вам надо скролить не саму страницу а контент в какой-то ее части, нужно вызывать `animate()` `scroll-top` от этой части, а не от `body`:

```
 $('.main').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vmtye285/4/

Comment: а как написать это все на чистом javascript без использования jquery ?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649149/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-jquery-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript?noredirect=1#comment928058_649149

Comment: Вот и отлично, не надо мешать эти два вопроса