# аналог кода jquery на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function closeModal(){
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function showModal(){
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}


function checkLoad() {
   var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

   function scroll(event) {
     var target = event.target;

     if (target.tagName != 'A') return;

     var id = document.querySelector(target.getAttribute('href'));
     var top = id.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;

     if (document.body.scrollTop > top) {
       (function animate() {

         if (document.body.scrollTop >= top) {
           window.scrollBy(0, -1);
           setTimeout(animate, 20);
         }
         event.preventDefault();
         return;
       })();
     }

     if (document.body.scrollTop < top) {
       (function animate() {

         if (document.body.scrollTop <= top) {
           window.scrollBy(0, 1);
           setTimeout(animate, 20);
         }
         event.preventDefault();
         return;
       })();
     }
   }

   menu.addEventListener('click', scroll);
 }

 addEventListener('load', checkLoad);
```

```css
.Window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Window:target {
 display: block;
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.Window > div {
  width: 1030px;
  height:640px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 74px -50px;
  background-size:925px 640px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px;
  background-color:white;
}
.share{
 position:absolute;
 right-12px;
 top:52px;
 left:992px;
}
.fbshare{
 position:absolute;
 right:-12px;
 top:509px;
 left:992px;
}
.twshare{
 position:absolute;
 right:-12px;
 top:546px;
 left:992px;
}
a{
 float:right;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
}
.leftcol{
 width:200px;
 height:590px;
 margin-top:-590px;
 float:left;
 background: url("images/lcolb.jpg") no-repeat;
 
}
.rigcol{
 width:45px;
 height:590px;
 margin-top:-590px;
 float:right;
 background-color:white;

}
.footer{
 position:fixed;
 top:600px;
 background-color:black;
 width:1030px;
 height:50px;
 

}
.learn{
 position:relative;
 top:-59px;
 width:260px;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#0066cc;
 float:right;
 
}
.learnT{
 font-size:20px;
 margin-right:50px;
}
.learn:hover {background:#3399FF;}
.learn:hover a {color:#fff}
hr{
 background-color:black;
 position:fixed;
 top:462px;
 width:40px;
 height:1px;
 margin-left:3px;
 border:0;
}
.Tfind{
 margin-top:380px;
 font-size:8px;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
}
.Thorizont{
 margin:0;
 position:relative;
 top:-20px;
 left:211px;
 color:white;
}
.hr2{
 width:1px;
 height:30px;
 background-color:white;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:200px;
 top:0px;
}
.hr3{
 width:170px;
 position:absolute;
 top:226px;
 left:5px;
}
.img1{
 margin-left:86px;
 margin-top:10px;
}
.img1{
 margin-left:46px;
 margin-top:12px;
}
.img2{
 margin-top:89px;
 margin-left:15px;
}
.videocontent{
  width:785px;
  height:443px;
  margin-top:107px;
 }
 .button1{
  width:732px;
  height:90px;
  border:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 .button2{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin-top:7px;
  margin-left:8px;
  border:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 .button3{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin-left:7px;
  margin-top:16px;
  border:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 .menu{
  width:200px;
  height:135px;
  margin-left:15px;
  font-size:18px;
  margin-top:22px;
 }
 .nav {
  font: 12pt;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin-top:22px;
  margin-left:9px;
  width:190px;
  height:45px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
 }
 .tabs
 {
  font: 12pt;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin-top:22px;
  width:190px;
  height:45px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
 }
 .nav  li a {
  display:block;
  width:190px;
  height:45px;
  line-height:40px;
  background:#fff;
  color:#000000;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
  
 }
 .nav li a:hover{
  transform: scaleY(1.2);
 }
 .img3{
  margin-top:55px;
  margin-left:35px;
 
 }
 .content{
  width:785px;
  height:490px;
 }
 .main{
  width:785px;
  height:590px;
  overflow:scroll;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:200px;
  position:relative;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <a href="#ModalOpen" title="modal">
  <button type="button" class="button1" id="modal_close" onclick="showModal();">
  <img src="images/ban.jpg"> 
  </button>
 </a>
 <div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
   <div class="content">
   <div class="main" >
    <section id="tab1">
     <video class="videocontent" controls poster="images/preview.jpg">
      <source src="images/ps.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
     </video>
    </section>
    <section id="tab2">
     <img src="images/background.jpg">
    </section>
   </div> 
    <div class="leftcol">
     <img class="img1" src="images/ps4.jpg">
     <img class="img2" src="images/logo.jpg">
       <div class="tabs" onclick ="checkLoad()> 
        <ul class="nav" id="menu">
         <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#tab1">Video</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#tab2">Horizon Zero Dawn</a>
          </br>
         </li>  
         <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#tab3">Through Aloy's Eyes</a>
         </li>
        </ul>  
       </div>
     <img src="images/esrb.jpg" class="img3"/> 
     
    </div>
    <div class="rigcol">
    <button type="button" class="button2" id="modal_close" onclick="closeModal();">
     <img src="images/x.jpg">
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="button3">
     <img src="images/share.jpg">
    </button>
    <hr>
     <p class="Tfind"> Find <br/>US ON</p>
    </hr>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fbshare">
     <img src="images/fb.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="twshare">
     <img src="images/twit.jpg">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
     <img src="images/i.jpg" class="img1">
     <hr class="hr2">
      <p class="Thorizont">Click on Horizon Zero Dawn to see the next era of mankind</p> 
      <div class="learn">
       <p class="learnT"><a href="#learnmore">Learn More <strong> > </strong></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

```js
function closeModal(){
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function showModal(){
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){

}, false )

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),

      top = $(id).offset().top;

    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
.Window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Window:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.Window > div {
  width: 1030px;
  height:640px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 74px -50px;
  background-size:925px 640px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px;
  background-color:white;
}
.share{
  position:absolute;
  right-12px;
  top:52px;
  left:992px;
}
.fbshare{
  position:absolute;
  right:-12px;
  top:509px;
  left:992px;
}
.twshare{
  position:absolute;
  right:-12px;
  top:546px;
  left:992px;
}
a{
  float:right;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}
.leftcol{
  width:200px;
  height:590px;
  margin-top:-590px;
  float:left;
  background: url("images/lcolb.jpg") no-repeat;

}
.rigcol{
  width:45px;
  height:590px;
  margin-top:-590px;
  float:right;
  background-color:white;

}
.footer{
  position:fixed;
  top:600px;
  background-color:black;
  width:1030px;
  height:50px;


}
.learn{
  position:relative;
  top:-59px;
  width:260px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#0066cc;
  float:right;

}
.learnT{
  font-size:20px;
  margin-right:50px;
}
.learn:hover {background:#3399FF;}
.learn:hover a {color:#fff}
hr{
  background-color:black;
  position:fixed;
  top:462px;
  width:40px;
  height:1px;
  margin-left:3px;
  border:0;
}
.Tfind{
  margin-top:380px;
  font-size:8px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
.Thorizont{
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
  top:-20px;
  left:211px;
  color:white;
}
.hr2{
  width:1px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:200px;
  top:0px;
}
.hr3{
  width:170px;
  position:absolute;
  top:226px;
  left:5px;
}
.img1{
  margin-left:86px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.img1{
  margin-left:46px;
  margin-top:12px;
}
.img2{
  margin-top:89px;
  margin-left:15px;
}
.videocontent{
    width:785px;
    height:443px;
    margin-top:107px;
  }
  .button1{
    width:732px;
    height:90px;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  .button2{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-left:8px;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  .button3{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:7px;
    margin-top:16px;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  .menu{
    width:200px;
    height:135px;
    margin-left:15px;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-top:22px;
  }
  .nav {
    font: 12pt;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:22px;
    margin-left:9px;
    width:190px;
    height:45px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
  .tabs
  {
    font: 12pt;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:22px;
    width:190px;
    height:45px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
  .nav  li a {
    display:block;
    width:190px;
    height:45px;
    line-height:40px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000000;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: all 0.6s linear;

  }
  .nav li a:hover{
  transform: scaleY(1.2);
  }
  .img3{
    margin-top:55px;
    margin-left:35px;

  }
  .content{
    width:785px;
    height:490px;
  }
  .main{
    width:785px;
    height:590px;
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:200px;
    position:relative;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#ModalOpen" title="modal">
  <button type="button" class="button1" id="modal_close" onclick="showModal();">
    <img src="images/ban.jpg">
  </button>
</a>
<div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
<div class="content">

<div class="main">
<section id="tab1">
  <video class="videocontent" controls poster="images/preview.jpg">
    <source src="images/ps.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  </video>
</section>
<section id="tab2">
  <img src="images/background.jpg">
</section>
</div><!-- /main -->

<div class="leftcol">
  <img class="img1" src="images/ps4.jpg">
  <img class="img2" src="images/logo.jpg">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul class="nav" id="menu">
    <li class="nav_item">
      <a href="#tab1">Video</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_item">
      <a href="#tab2">Horizon Zero Dawn</a>
      </br>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_item">
      <a href="#tab3">Through Aloy's Eyes</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /tabs -->
  <img src="images/esrb.jpg" class="img3"/>
</div><!-- /leftcol -->

<div class="rigcol">
  <button type="button" class="button2" id="modal_close" onclick="closeModal();">
    <img src="images/x.jpg">
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="button3">
    <img src="images/share.jpg">
  </button>
  <hr>
  <p class="Tfind"> Find <br/>US ON</p>
  </hr>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fbshare">
    <img src="images/fb.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="twshare">
    <img src="images/twit.jpg">
  </a>
</div><!-- /rigcol -->

<div class="footer">
  <img src="images/i.jpg" class="img1">
  <hr class="hr2">
  <p class="Thorizont">Click on Horizon Zero Dawn to see the next era of mankind</p>
  <div class="learn">
    <p class="learnT"><a href="#learnmore">Learn More <strong> > </strong></a></p>
  </div>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /Window -->
```

Можно ли переписать такой код на javascript?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();

     var id  = $(this).attr('href'),

        top = $(id).offset().top;

    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Элементы `a` внутри `#menu` могут динамически меняться или они всегда одни и те же?

Comment: `jquery` это библиотека Javascrpt. Все что можно сделать на jquery можно сделать и на чистом JS. так что ответ - можно.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference--net-23703 посмотрите, почитайте и используйте то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @Oleksandr `$('ul').on('click', 'a', fn)` там некорректно реализован, если внутри `a` будут ещё какие-то элементы то это не сработает

Comment: Да, можно переписать, но ты получишь просто ужасную жопаболь особенно с отборкой элементов в JS все очень не сладко. Например document.getElmentsByTagName("a").onclick = function(){}; не сработает. Сработает только document.getElmentsByTagName("a")[0].onclick = function(){}. И меня это очень бесит, так как надо указывать отдельный элемент из возвращаемого массива.

Comment: @EugenEray как правильно все это написать  ?

Comment: @EugenEray есть такая штука как document.querySelector() которая избавляет от того, что вы говорите)

Comment: @ddeadlink вы можете написать этот код на чистом js ?

Comment: @andrey анимацию в лучшем случае нужно делать на css. Если добавите html - могу

Comment: @ddeadlink добавил

Comment: @Calvin у вас не рабочий код. `id` всегда будет возвращать `null`, так как у вас не висит атрибут ссылки на элементе меню. Если ваш вопрос касается не только трансфера кода, а и реализации и отладки - извольте обновить существующий вопрос. P.S. не создавайте дупликаты своих же вопросов

Comment: @ddeadlink как просто переевести этот jquery код в javascript правильно , вопрос заключается лишь в этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот и он:

```js
 'use strict';

 function checkLoad() {
   var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

   function scroll(event) {
     var target = event.target;

     if (target.tagName != 'A') return;

     var id = document.querySelector(target.getAttribute('href'));
     var top = id.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;

     if (document.body.scrollTop > top) {
       (function animate() {

         if (document.body.scrollTop >= top) {
           window.scrollBy(0, -1);
           setTimeout(animate, 20);
         }
         event.preventDefault();
         return;
       })();
     }

     if (document.body.scrollTop < top) {
       (function animate() {

         if (document.body.scrollTop <= top) {
           window.scrollBy(0, 1);
           setTimeout(animate, 20);
         }
         event.preventDefault();
         return;
       })();
     }
   }

   menu.addEventListener('click', scroll);
 }

 addEventListener('load', checkLoad);
```

- Я точно не знаю как работает метод **animate** у jQuery, но я тестировал ваш код, считаю, что полностью добился анимации как в нем.
- Ваш код мне показался странно работает, но вы просили перевести в js именно его.
- Просьба, в следующий раз выкладывайте HTML и CSS более подготовленные(с загруженными картинками и т.д.).

Comment: что то не получилось , посмотрите на правильность написания моего кода

Comment: @Calvin Как я писал, ваш код на мой взгляд работает странно, я сделал аналогию на javascript, в своих комментариях вы просили именно этого(не смотреть на назначение скрипта), если что-то не так, то нужно вам описать что должно выполняться и как(для этого нужен корректный html и css). Могу посмотреть на вашем сайте.